# Meaning of Matt 5:18

Tags: matthew, jesus

> Matt 5:18 For verily I say unto you, Till heaven and earth pass, one
> jot or one tittle shall in no wise pass from the law, till all be
> fulfilled.

What is it that has to be fulfilled? If it's Messianic prophecies that Jesus had to fulfill, then not all of them are fulfilled yet, for example this one:

> Isa 2:4 And he shall judge among the nations, and shall rebuke many
> people: and they shall beat their swords into plowshares, and their
> spears into pruninghooks: nation shall not lift up sword against
> nation, neither shall they learn war any more.

So they have to be, or will be fulfilled when Jesus comes back. So does mean law of Torah is valid until Jesus returns?

Comment: Welcome to the group. Your last sentence in incomplete. Please edit.

Answer (score 2):

The OP's verse is part of a larger section in Matt 5

> **17** Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets. I have not come to abolish them, but to fulfill them. **18**
> For I tell you truly, until heaven and earth pass away, not a single
> jot, not a stroke of a pen, will disappear from the Law until
> everything is accomplished. **19** So then, whoever breaks one of the
> least of these commandments and teaches others to do likewise will be
> called least in the kingdom of heaven; but whoever practices and
> teaches them will be called great in the kingdom of heaven.

This is a very controversial passage with three separate positions being taken by various peoples:

1. Those who assert that Jesus fulfilled the law and so it does not have to kept.  That is the law is abrogated and done away with.  This contradicts V17.
2. Those who believe that Jesus fulfilled the law but did not abolish it and thus the entire Torah, including all the ceremonial system must be kept.  If this is true, then Jesus fulfilled nothing.
3. Those who believe that the ceremonial law was a system pointing to Jesus, which He fulfilled, and the moral law was not abandoned and so still in force.  This, or something similar was the common position of most churches until the early 20th century.  See appendix below.

That is:

- Jesus fulfilled the ceremonial law.  Specifically, Jesus was the Lamb of God (John 1:29); Jesus was the bread of life as symbolized by the shew bread (John 6:35-51); The light of the Menorah represented Jesus (John 8:12, 9:5); Jesus was the door (John 10:7-9); Jesus is represented as our great High Priest and intercessor in heaven (Heb 4:16, 7:25, 10:22, Rom 8:26, 34, 1 John 2:1, 2, 1 Tim 2:5, John 14:6); The Temple represented Jesus’ body (John 2:19-21), etc.
- However, the NT repeats the moral laws as still binding such as: Eph 6:2, 3 quotes Deut 5:16, Ex 20:12; James 2:11 quotes Ex 20:13; Rom 13:9 quotes Ex 20:13-15, 17; Rom 7:7 quotes Ex 20:17; Acts 23:5 quotes Ex 22:28; Heb 9:20 quotes Ex 24:8; 1 Peter 1:16 quotes Lev 19:2; Matt 22:39, James 2:8, Gal 5:14 quotes Lev 19:18; 2 Tim 2:19 quotes Num 16:5; Matt 19:18, 19 quotes Deut 5:16-20; Mark 12:32 quotes Deut 6:4; 2 Cor 13:1 quotes Deut 19:15; Matt 5:31, 19:7 quotes Deut 24:1; 1 Cor 9:9 quotes Deut 25:4; Rom 12:19 quotes Deut 32:35; Heb 10:30 quotes Deut 32:35, 36; Acts 15:29 quotes food sacrificed, no blood, no strangled animal meat, no fornication, etc.

The latter is confirmed by Jesus who expanded the scope and reach of the moral laws in His sermon on the mount (Matt 5, 6, 7) to include thoughts and intents, etc.

**APPENDIX - Historical Positions**

Many of these significant theologians have seen a distinction in the Torah between the ceremonial law (which was fulfilled) and moral law which is still in force:

- Thomas Aquinas discussed the tripartite law, moral, ceremonial, and judicial, in his “Summa Theologica”, section entitled "Treatise on the Law" and more specifically in questions 99-105.
- Luther appears to believe in a bipartite Law, when in The Bondage of the Will, he referred to "the civil or moral law”. (Luther Bondage CXLVI)
- Calvin, in book 2 of Institutes of the Christian Religion (2.7, 2.8.31), presented a bipartite view when he discussed the law, its moral and ceremonial aspects.  However, later, in book 4 of the Institutes (4.20.14), when he discussed civil government, he presented a tripartite law when he stated: "the well-known division which distributes the whole law of God, as promulgated by Moses, into the moral, the ceremonial, and the judicial law.”
- The Westminster Confession (1646) set out a tripartite law
- The Baptist Confession of Faith (1689) almost copies the Westminster Confession in assuming a tripartite law (see Chapter 19).  (According to the 2000 Baptist Faith and Message, no such division exists.)

Comment: + 1 I appreciate your setting forth various approaches on this.... a good example of how to handle questions that might otherwise be closed as opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to supplement @Dottard's good answer: the entire law remained in force for Jewish Christians (the audience here was Jewish) but only the moral commandments were required for Gentile believers.

Paul's letters are quite clear that obedience the the OT Law will not bring redemption, which comes about through faith in Jesus' atoning death and resurrection. So, if Matthew's report of Jesus' words needs to harmonize with Paul's teaching, many naturally believe that the answer must be based on either  @Dottard's approach # 1 or # 3: "Jesus fulfilled the law and so it does not have to kept," (#1) with the possible exception of the moral commandments (# 3). Hebrews 8:13 is even more clear: the OT law - at least the ceremonial laws - is obsolete (@Dotttard's approach # 3).

However, if we take Matthew's gospel on its own terms without filtering it through the teaching of Paul, the possibility exist that Jesus meant what the plain sense of the text says:

> Until heaven and earth pass away, not the smallest letter or the
> smallest part of a letter will pass from the law, until all things
> have taken place... 20 I tell you, unless your righteousness surpasses
> that of the scribes and Pharisees, you will not enter into the kingdom
> of heaven.

Understanding this saying as guidance for the church literally until the end of the world explains why the earliest Christian community (that of Jerusalem) continued to follow the Law scrupulously. It allowed Gentile Christians more leeway (Acts 15), exempting them from circumcision and most of the kosher laws. But this was a standard understanding of the requirements of the Torah, and Jewish Christians still had to follow both the moral and the ceremonial laws. Thus Acts 21 reports a conversation between the leaders of the Jerusalem Church and Paul:

> Brother, you see how many thousands of believers there are from among
> the Jews, and they are all zealous observers of the law. 21 They have
> been informed that you are teaching all the Jews who live among the
> Gentiles to abandon Moses and that you are telling them not to
> circumcise their children or to observe their customary practices. 22
> What is to be done?

This is immediately followed by Paul's participation in a Temple ceremony to demonstrate that "you yourself live in observance of the law." (21:24) So in both Matthew and Luke, Jewish Christians followed the entire law carefully, believing that this is what Jesus taught them to do.

**Conclusion**: Taken on its own, Matthew's version of Jesus' teaching indicates that the whole Law was still a requirement for Jewish Christians and would remain so forever (until heaven and earth pass away). Taken in light of other NT teachings, the words of Jesus quoted in the OP are not literal: they were fulfilled at the time of the Resurrection, even though heaven and earth did not pass away.

---

*Note*: Although Matthew emphasizes the need to follow the Law, this does not mean that he believed Jesus agreed with a strict interpretation of the Law. This explains why in Matthew's account Jesus is often at odds with various Pharisees about how the Law should be applied (hand washing before meals, healing on the Sabbath, etc.)

*Note2* If Acts' implication is correct that Paul himself lived as a Jew, then his letters are not meant to contradict the idea that  Jewish Christians, as opposed to Gentile believers, had to follow the entire law. However, Paul himself says that he "became like a Jew" only when among Jews (1 Corinthians 9:20) and did not consider himself to be under the law.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Many people are confused by this verse because they do not recognize the Hebrew idiom “heaven and earth.”  It is a compound metaphor that God used to refer to the agreement between God and the people of Israel (Jacob’s descendants), or the Mosaic covenant.  Moses told them,

> 25 `When thou begettest sons and sons' sons, and ye have become old in the land, and have done corruptly, and have made a graven image, a similitude of anything, and have done the evil thing in the eyes of Jehovah, to provoke Him to anger: -- 26 I have caused to testify against you this day the heavens and the earth, that ye do perish utterly hastily from off the land whither ye are passing over the Jordan to possess it; ye do not prolong days upon it, but are utterly destroyed;  (Deu. 4:25-26, YLT)

What would testify against them?

> 24 And it cometh to pass, when Moses finisheth to write the words of this law on a book till their completion, 25 that Moses commandeth the Levites bearing the ark of the covenant of Jehovah, saying, 26 `Take this Book of the Law, and thou hast set it on the side of the ark of the covenant of Jehovah your God, and it hath been there against thee for a witness;  (Deu. 31:24-26, YLT)

It was the law, the Mosaic covenant which God called “heaven and earth” that was to be the witness that would testify against the people. It was symbolic language for His creation of His people (Isa. 51:13-16), the agreement between God and Israel (Ex. 19:5-8)

When God prophesied in Isa. 65:17 and Isa. 66:22 that He was creating “new heavens and a new earth,” He was not speaking literally, but covenantally. The immediate sense was to re-establish the covenant with Israel upon their return from the Babylonian captivity.  The fuller sense was looking forward to the new covenant He would establish under the gospel of Christ.

The Jews used the phrase “heaven and earth” to refer to the temple where God met with man.  One of the meanings of the architectural symbols and elements used within that temple represented the literal heavens and earth of God’s creation. (1) (2)
Therefore, Matt. 5:18 is understood in the language of the first century Jews as “till the Mosaic Covenant pass…” or “till the temple passes…”  That was what they would have understood from the phrase “heaven and earth.”   Jesus was not speaking of the literal heavens and earth of the literal cosmos.

That temple “heaven and earth” passed away at its destruction in AD 70 by the Romans whom God used to carry out His judgment against those wicked who had crucified their promised Messiah.  And, that old covenant that was waxing old (Heb. 8:13) when the book of Hebrews was written in about AD 65-66 was completely fulfilled by and through Jesus’ sacrifice for our sins.  Those were the last days of that old Mosaic covenant.

Our new covenant with YHVH is under the gospel of Christ, and He is our only sacrifice, our only way to our Father in heaven (John 14:6).  There are no other sacrifices to be made (Heb. 10:26).  We are no longer under the Mosaic covenant.

Notes:

1. https://www.reenactingtheway.com/blog/when-heaven-and-earth-passed-away-everything-changed879420187179853150181
2. https://redemptivebiblestudies.com/creation-and-temple-in-hebrew-thought/

Answer (score 0):

Let's read Matthew 5:17-18 together;

> 17 “Do not think that I have come to abolish **the Law or the Prophets**; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them. 18 For truly I tell you, until heaven and earth disappear, not the smallest letter, not the least stroke of a pen, will by any means disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished. (NIV)

The **Law** refers to the first five books of the Old Testament, also known as the Pentateuch. The **Prophets** refer to the remaining books of the Old Testament. Together they form the Old Testament as a whole. In Matthew 5:17, Jesus declared that he came to fulfill everything that has been written in the Old Testament, including every word that has been prophesized by the Prophets. Therefore, Paul wrote in Rome 3:21, *"But now apart from the law the righteousness of God has been made known, to which **the Law and the Prophets** testify".* The Law and the Prophets are the witnesses of Jesus Christ, and they cannot be abolished or changed, even a little bit of it. They testify to the righteousness of God, which is revealed through faith in Jesus Christ.

There may be some confusion about whether the Law described in Matthew 5:17-18 refers to the Mosaic law. In fact, the purpose of the Mosaic law is to awaken people's consciousness of sin (Romans 3:20). Jesus' mission is much bigger than this. He came to do the will of God, as He said in John 6:38, ***"For I have come down from heaven not to do my will but to do the will of him who sent me"***. Therefore it is the will of God Jesus is fulfilling, not the Mosaic Law.